# how to: sql statement select all from table, where any letter user inputs, matches any letter included in a name property

Tags: sql, sinatra

i have a search box on a web app, and i want the user input in the box to be matched with relevant record.  At the moment, i can get the search to find by the whole name, i.e, the user has to type in the full name accurately, to get a match.

However, i want the user to be able to type in any letter included, and the function return any name that has that letter included
i.e Jimmy, search for i and get a match

this is my current ruby method, including sql statement, which is what i need to amend somehow

```
def self.search(input)
  sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (first_name LIKE '#{input.capitalize}') OR (last_name LIKE '#{input.capitalize}')  "
  results = SqlRunner.run(sql)
  return results.map { |customer| Customer.new(customer) }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use wildcard character. % is the wildcard character that replace it self with any string. YOu code should look something like this:

```
(first_name LIKE '%#{input.capitalize}%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on '%' special character:

Maybe this works for you.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (first_name LIKE %' + #{input.capitalize} + '%) OR (last_name LIKE %' + #{input.capitalize} + '%)  "
```

ps: not sure if thats how you concat strings in ruby.